# How to UPDATE multiple values in T-SQL with the stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table like that:

```
CREATE TABLE Ticket
(
    id_Ticket int PRIMARY KEY,
    id_Passengers int,
    id_Schedule int,
    Ticket_Price money,
    Nomer_Mest int
)
```

DECLARE and EXEC:

```
DECLARE @Ticket_Price int, @id_Ticket int;
SET @Ticket_Price = 50 
SET @id_Ticket = 9

EXEC AlterTicket @Ticket_Price, @id_Ticket
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AlterTicket
    @Ticket_Price Money, @id_Ticket int, @Nomer_Mest int;
AS
    UPDATE Ticket 
    SET Ticket_Price = @Ticket_Price
    WHERE id_Ticket = @id_Ticket

    UPDATE Ticket 
    SET Nomer_Mest = @Nomer_Mest 
    WHERE id_Ticket = @id_Ticket
```

I also have to assign a value for 2 parameters at once. But let's say
I need to change only Ticket_Price, I won't change the parameters of
the Stored procedure.

Comment: I need to do a stored procedure to change data in tables. But in my approach, in order to change 1 value (Ticket_Price), I need to assign another value to (Nomer_Mest). I need the assignment of a value for Nomer_Test to be optional, but I could change it if I needed it.

Comment: By the way, `Ticket_Price money` vs `DECLARE @Ticket_Price int`. I'd advice against `money` anyway, `decimal` is preferable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by changing the order of parameters, and you can check for `NULL`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AlterTicket
    @id_Ticket int, @Nomer_Mest int, @Ticket_Price Money
AS
    UPDATE Ticket 
    SET Ticket_Price = COALESCE(@Ticket_Price, Ticket_Price), Nomer_Mest = COALESCE(@Nomer_Mest, Nomer_Mest) 
    WHERE id_Ticket = @id_Ticket;
```

Call it with:

```
EXEC AlterTicket @id_Ticket, @Nomer_Mest, NULL;
```

Or:

```
EXEC AlterTicket @id_Ticket, NULL, @Ticket_Price;
```

As I said in a comment, I also strongly advice to consider using `decimal` instead of `money`.

Comment: This is what i need. but i got a problem - (0 row`s affected )

Comment: @1101 fixed some typos, which should've given an error. Works in the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=78385277bf35224d1d2785477286d14d) Cetin generously provided

Comment: I think I made a mistake in EXEC, assigned it in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

You can update multiple values in a single update:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AlterTicket
    @Ticket_Price Money, @id_Ticket int, @Nomer_Mest int;
AS
    UPDATE Ticket 
    SET Ticket_Price = @Ticket_Price, Nomer_Mest = @Nomer_Mest
    WHERE id_Ticket = @id_Ticket;
```

Comment: That's what I want to do, but I also have to assign a value for 2 parameters at once. But let's say I need to change only Ticket_Price, I won't change the parameters of the Stored procedure. I hope an understandable example, I just don't know how to explain.

Comment: @1101, sorry I don't understand what you mean. You need to give a sample.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you meant this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AlterTicket
    @id_Ticket int, @Ticket_Price Money = null, @Nomer_Mest int = null
AS
begin
  if @Ticket_Price is not null and @Nomer_mest is not null
    UPDATE Ticket 
    SET Ticket_Price = @Ticket_Price, Nomer_Mest = @Nomer_Mest
    WHERE id_Ticket = @id_Ticket;
  else if @Ticket_Price is not null
    UPDATE Ticket 
    SET Ticket_Price = @Ticket_Price
    WHERE id_Ticket = @id_Ticket;
  else if @Nomer_Mest is not null
    UPDATE Ticket 
    SET Nomer_Mest = @Nomer_Mest
    WHERE id_Ticket = @id_Ticket;
end
```

Here is [DBFiddle demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=33a65f98e7dab9efc57071d79d9e8c49)

This has advantage that, on a long list of parameters you can pass only the needed ones.

Comment: Yes, this is it logically, but can I change the value from Null to NOT NULL at exec? Without going back to the procedure itself

Comment: Can I change the type using Alter Column?

Comment: @1101, did you ever check the DBFiddle demo that I gave link to? I really don't understand what you may be asking.

Comment: No. I had to choose from two which one to replace to change

Answer (score 0):

Building on the work of @HoneyBadger I would use defaults in your stored procedure definition and then the assignment method of calling it e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AlterTicket
(
    @id_Ticket int
    , @Nomer_Mest int = null
    , @Ticket_Price Money = null
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

    UPDATE Ticket SET
        Ticket_Price = COALESCE(@Ticket_Price, Ticket_Price)
        , Nomer_Mest = COALESCE(@Nomer_Mest, Nomer_Mest) 
    WHERE id_Ticket = @id_Ticket;

    RETURN 0;
END;
```

Call it with:

```
EXEC AlterTicket @id_Ticket = @id_Ticket, @Nomer_Mest = @Nomer_Nest;
```

Or:

```
EXEC AlterTicket @id_Ticket = @id_Ticket, @Ticket_Price = @Ticket_Price;
```

This form of calling a stored procedure has two benefits:

1. You don't have to get the order of your parameters right.
2. If you ever need to add a new parameter in future you don't have to update every reference to your stored procedure.